# How to install a pip module from its master branch on github?

Tags: python, git, pip, chalice

I've started using the Python Chalice framework and I found out I need a bugfix that was merged less than 24 hours ago into the framework's master branch, through this PR:

https://github.com/aws/chalice/pull/1116

My experience with Python modules is limited to typing `pip install` and watching the magic happen. How can I install Chalice straight off GitHub's master branch instead?

Comment: why not pull the code from github from the master branch and use the source code to install the module?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I think you’re just restating my question with different words

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install

Comment: https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pip conveniently has built-in Git support.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user_name/repo_name
```

Answer (score 2):

[@Draconis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161126/2988730) is the simplest in terms of manual steps. If you already have the repo, you can use its `setup.py`:

```
./setup.py install
```

Or if you want to specifically use `pip`:

```
pip install -e .
```

Both commands are shown being run from the project root that contains `setup.py`.

If you got the repo to do development in it, you may want to do

```
./setup.py develop
```

This will symlink your working directory into your Python installation's site packages, so all your changes show up instantly as you work.